# Update collection fields with JPAUpdateClause

Tags: java, hibernate, querydsl

I'm trying to update a Set type field with the following

```
    final QFooEntity fooEntity = QFooEntity.fooEntity;
    final JPAUpdateClause updateClause = new JPAUpdateClause(entityManager, fooEntity);
    updateClause.where(fooEntity.id.in(ids))
                .set(fooEntity.barIds, barIds)
                .execute();
```

but I get the following error

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set .=. where id in ...
```

I can update regular fields without any problem so I assume it's because barIds is a Set

Here's the entity

```
public class FooEntity {
...
      @ElementCollection
      @CollectionTable(
        name = "bar_foo",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                name = "fooId"),
        uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(
                columnNames = { "fooId", "barId" }))
      @Column(name = "barId")
      private Set<Long>         barIds = Sets.newHashSet();
}
```

Is this possible with JPAUpdateClause or I have to write my own sql string?

Comment: did you find a solution for this problem ?